# C# Regex - Get feat. out of Audiofile name

Tags: c#, regex

I am having a Audiofile whichs name is "The Kemist, Nyanda ft. Braindead - Mayhem 2 (Dj Reg Refix)". Now I want to extract the featuring with Regex (Yes, Regex, cause this sample is just the beginning of multiple operations which will be much more simpler with Regex), so I will get "Braindead ".

All I have so far is this:

```
    public const string Feature1 = "ft?.\\s";
    public const string Feature2 = "feat?.\\s";
    public const string Feature3 = "featuring\\s";

    public const string Hyphen1 = "-";
    public const string Comma1 = ",";
    public const string And = "&";

    public const string BracketOpen1 = "(";
    public const string BracketOpen2 = "[";
    public const string BracketOpen3 = "{";

    public const string BracketClosed1 = ")";
    public const string BracketClosed2 = "]";
    public const string BracketClosed3 = "}";

    /// <summary>
    /// The words / Signs / Chars which indicate a new Artist / Feature / Title
    /// </summary>
    public static List<string> WordStopper = new List<string>()
    {
        Feature1, Feature2, Feature3,
        BracketOpen1, BracketOpen2, BracketOpen3,
        BracketClosed1, BracketClosed2, BracketClosed3,
        Hyphen1, Comma1
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// The start of a new feature
    /// </summary>
    public static List<string> FeatureBeginning = new List<string>()
    {
        Feature1,
        Feature2,
        Feature3
    };

    private static List<string> GetFeatures(string filename)
    {
        // Set the left side
        string starter = string.Join("|", FeatureBeginning.Select(w => w));

        // Set the right side
        string stopper = string.Join("|", WordStopper.Select(w => w));

        // Get the matches
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(filename, $"{starter}(\\.+){stopper}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        return null;
    }
```

This one gives me following error: "{System.ArgumentException: parsing 'ft?.\s|feat?.\s|featuring\s(.+)ft?.\s|feat?.\s|featuring\s|(|[|{|)|]|}|-|,' - Not enough )'s."

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried matching the parentheses and seeing if you open the same number as you close? The `Not enough )'s` is a **very** big clue.

Comment: Try breaking down your RegEx into smaller parts. Then reintroduce parts until it doesn't work. Then [find out why](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference).

Comment: There is my solution. btw nice program idea

Comment: You could also make use of the escape function: System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape("("); //returns "\\("
BUT watch out. this would not work with Feature1-3 because you have actual makros in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
public const string Feature1 = @"ft?.\s";
public const string Feature2 = @"feat?.\s";
public const string Feature3 = @"featuring\s";

public const string Hyphen1 = "-";
public const string Comma1 = ",";
public const string And = "&";

public const string BracketOpen1 = @"\(";
public const string BracketOpen2 = @"\[";
public const string BracketOpen3 = @"\{";

public const string BracketClosed1 = @"\)";
public const string BracketClosed2 = @"\]";
public const string BracketClosed3 = @"\}";

/// <summary>
/// The words / Signs / Chars which indicate a new Artist / Feature / Title
/// </summary>
public static List<string> WordStopper = new List<string>()
{
    Feature1, Feature2, Feature3,
    BracketOpen1, BracketOpen2, BracketOpen3,
    BracketClosed1, BracketClosed2, BracketClosed3,
    Hyphen1, Comma1
};

/// <summary>
/// The start of a new feature
/// </summary>
public static List<string> FeatureBeginning = new List<string>()
{
    Feature1,
    Feature2,
    Feature3
};

public static List<string> GetFeatures(string filename)
{
    // Set the left side
    string starter = "(" + string.Join(")|(", FeatureBeginning.ToArray()) + ")";

    // Set the right side
    string stopper = "(" + string.Join(")|(", WordStopper.ToArray()) + ")";

    // Get the matches
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(filename, "(?<=(" + starter + "))(.+?)(?=(" + stopper + "))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

    return null;
}
```

You Have to check some of your Expression where not escaped. Also you where matching everything until the last stopper not until the first one.

Comment: Always nice helping out.